# What are some steps to take for securing a Linux server that aren't in this list of obvious ones?

Tags: linux, webserver, ssh

Obvious things:

1. Disable `root` login (rather, don't enable it)
2. Secure SSH (no `root` login, key auth only, timeout after inactivity, whitelist users who can SSH in, etc.)
3. IP Tables firewall whitelisting only the proper traffic on 80/443/22
4. Update all packages
5. Disable Control-Alt-Delete for the console

The OS is Ubuntu 12.04.1 x86-64 (server) and the use is as a web application server. The software used is:

1. Nginx (run as `www-data`)
2. Supervisor (run as `root` with no HTTP server or RPC server)
3. uWSGI (run as `www-data`)
4. Celery (run as `www-data`)
5. Redis (run as `www-data`)
6. Memcached (run as `www-data`)

I ask because I'm not sure what things that are installed with Ubuntu 12.04.1 which might be have potential security vulnerabilities, which things I may have accidentally left off my "obvious" checklist and which of the packages I've mentioned above which might have security vulnerabilities (all installed as packages vs manually compiling, btw).

Comment: Might add some SYN packet rate limiting on the IPTables firewall too, it won't stop a DDoS attack, but it it can help weather the effects.

Comment: Was it ubuntu server edition installed? Not desktop edition stripped?

Comment: @ewanm89 - yeah, server edition. Thanks btw (for the tip on SYN packet rate limiting).

Comment: total and complete disregard for application separation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Run your web application as a different user than everyone else.  This is what www-data is for!!!!!
- Remove write access to your web root!  (And only your web application (www-data) should have
  read/execute)
- Use a Web Application Firewall (WAF).  [Naxsi](http://code.google.com/p/naxsi/) for Nginx is an
  option however mod_security is a better WAF.
- Remove access to port 22 using [Port Knocking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_knocking) Or [Bastion
  Host](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bastion_host) (Bonus points for using both!)
- Force HTTPS only to avoid [OWASP a9](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A9-Insufficient_Transport_Layer_Protection) violations.  HTTP should only
  be used to set HSTS and redirects to HTTPS.
- Last I checked Ubuntu doesn't have AppArmor rule sets for ngix,  where as
  they do for the LAMP install.  Also be aware that nginx is very young
  and as a result [more advisories are released for ngix](http://nginx.org/en/security_advisories.html) than
  [Apache]
- setup [apt autoupdate](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/automatic-updates.html) for security related updates.
- If you have the money,  get a pentest

Comment: Thanks - regarding your "total and complete disregard..." comment: Did you mean, because I've used `www-data` so gratuitously? Which programs should be running as `www-data`? My web application is really a combination of `uWSGI` and `Nginx`. Should both run as `www-data`?

Comment: @orokusaki Ok,  you probably have never written an exploit.  But the best exploits are using the services against each other. For instance using the database to write a .php file in the web root. AppArmor helps with this,  but your using ngix and everyone is running as www-data so you absolutely no separation what so ever. You just threw a bunch of criminals with construction equipment in the same jail cell.

Comment: Thanks Rook. That's good info to have. I did typo when I said `Memcached` and `Redis` would run as `www-data`, but the rest were `www-data` :( lesson learned the easy way though :)